# How to get all (including invited) managed users via rest api in Box

Tags: java, box

Been looking for ability to retrieve all users from Box including ones who were invited via email. All of them located in admin console but when i try to retrieve them through box-sdk like that:

```
BoxConfig boxConfig = BoxConfig.readFrom(reader); // jwt scenario
BoxAPIConnection serviceAccountClient = BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.getAppEnterpriseConnection(boxConfig);
Iterable<BoxUser.Info> infos = BoxUser.getAllEnterpriseUsers(serviceAccountClient);
for (BoxUser.Info info : infos) {
    log.info("info. name: {} ; login: {} ; id: {}", info.getName(), info.getLogin(), info.getID());
}
```

I get only users which have been created via "service account".
So, how can i retrieve ALL of the managed users?

Or is it possible to retrieve it, let's say, by knowing its email or name?

Further i'd like to use rest-API on their behalf. 
Maybe it's required for such users to login only with 3-legged oAuth2 process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enable "Enterprise" on Application Access and enable "Manager Users" for Application Scopes and then reauthorize your app, you should be able to get all managed users as well.

Comment: Thank you, i forgot to reauthorize it